# paho mqtt on_message callback thread

Tags: python, asynchronous, mqtt, paho

I implemented a paho-mqtt client to do a specific task when a message arrives. Therefore I use the on_message callback function like that:

```
def on_message():
    do time-intensive things
```

The callbacks run in one thread in the background because I use a non-blocking loop for mqtt.

My question is what exactly happens in this thread? do those tasks collect in a row every time on_message is called ? Because in my case weird things happen: the tasks just interrupt each other

Does someone know how to use async in this case ? I tried sth. like

```
def on_message():
   await time-intensive_task
```

But one can't call await in a non-async function

please help